# How to write data to a view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I'm programming my first Django website.
I want to pass data from my view to my template.

my view:

```
from django.views import generic


class AboutView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(AboutView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['test'] = 'This testtext should be displayed in the Webpage'
        return ctx
```

my template:

```
{% extends 'site_base.html' %}
{% block body %}

{% endblock %}
```

How to display the testtext in the body-block?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a basic issue that is well covered in the introductory tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference the context variable name using double curly braces:

```
{{ test }}
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables) for a longer description.

Comment: i tried thist: "  {{ ctx['test'] }}"

Comment: Please review the docs. `{{ ctx['test']}}` is incorrect. When you render a template (such as through a `TemplateView`) you generally provide a context dictionary via `get_context_data`. You do not need to specifically reference the containing context variable, at least as long as your response is produced by a subclass of `TemplateView`, but you should get used to thinking about what variables you provide to your template context.

Answer (score 0):

you can add an attrib to it like this :

```
context_object_name = 'ab_list'
```

and then in your html :

```
{{ ab_list }}
```